# How to share scope and variables in Node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, scope

I'm writing a node program and I want several functions contained in separate files to access and modify the same scope of variables without defining them in the global scope.

The solution I found is using a module to share its scope but it seems a bit tricky.

Here's the file tree :

```
- index.js
- file-a.js
- file-b.js
- shared-scope.js
```

`index.js` :

```js
require('./file-a')
require('./file-b')
```

`file-a.js` :

```js
const sharedScope = require('./shared-scope');

sharedScope.foo = 'bar'
```

`file-b.js` :

```js
const sharedScope = require('./shared-scope');

console.log(sharedScope) // Prints { foo: 'bar' }
```

`shared-scope.js` :

```js
module.exports = {};
```

What do you think about it? Is this a good way of sharing a scope between modules?

Comment: That's not a scope, that's a shared object. You cannot really "share" a scope except for the global scope or an `eval` scope.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, that's called a singleton. Some might say that any global, shared state is bad, but if that's what you want, this is a perfectly fine and simple way to do it.

The most obvious alternative is to define the data in one place and then in other modules, define functions which work on the data.

`file-b.js`:

```
module.exports = function (data) {
    data.foo = "bar";
}
```

`index.js`:

```
const assignFoo = require('./file-b.js');
const data = {};
assignFoo(data);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I already heard about the Singleton but I thought it was something more complex and class related.